# What exactly is a foreign key?

Tags: database, foreign-keys

Ok. So I know what a primary key in  DB is. If you have a table in a database, a primary key is a single value that is unique to each row in your table. For example:

```
id   | name    | whatever
-------------------------
1      Alice     ....
2      Bob       ....
45     Eve       ....
988    ....      ....
```

So I need a good, simple example to explain what exactly a foreign key is. Because I just don't get it :)

---

**Edit:** OK it's pretty easy, I guess I was over-complicating the problem.

So one final question, the only restriction on foreign keys is that it they are a valid primary key value in the table I am referring to?

Comment: "the only restriction on foreign keys is..." That's not a "restriction", that's the definition: an FK IS a valid primary key on another table.

Comment: "...a primary key is a single value..." yes, so long as you recognize that "value" is _not_ synonymous with "column." It's perfectly valid for the primary key to be multiple values.

Comment: Grrr. Can't edit comments. Last sentence should read: "It's perfectly valid for the primary key to be multiple COLUMNS".

Comment: It is the only restriction of being aforeign key, you can still put other restrictions onthe column if you like.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A foreign key is a field that points to a primary key of another table.

Example:

```
Table Name - Users

UserID    UserName    UserRoleID
1         JohnD       1
2         CourtneyC   1
3         Benjamin    2

Table Name - UserRoles

UserRoleID    Desc
1             Admin
2             Moderator
```

You can see that Users.UserRoleID is a foreign key which points to the primary key UserRoles.UserRoleID

The use of foreign keys makes setting up relationships on other tables simple, allowing you to link together the data of multiple tables in a nice way:

Example:

```
SELECT
    a.UserID, 
    a.UserName, 
    b.Desc as [UserRole]
FROM 
    Users a INNER JOIN 
        UserRoles b ON a.UserRoleID = b.UserRoleID
```

Output would then be:

```
UserID    UserName    User Role
1         JohnD       Admin
2         CourneyC    Admin
3         Benjamin    Moderator
```

Comment: No, not (only) a PK. In the relational model, a FK references a CK. (One of which might be called the PK.) (PKs don't matter to relational theory.) In SQL, a FK references a UNIQUE. (Which might be a PK). A CK is a superkey containing no smaller superkey. Some relational presentations might define a FK to reference a superkey. An SQL PK is just a UNIQUE NOT NULL & like any SQL UNIQUE might contain a smaller one.

Answer (score 17):

Let's say you have another field, which is the home city:

```
id   | name    | city
-------------------------
1      Alice     San Francisco
2      Bob       New York
45     Eve       New York
988    Bill      San Francisco
```

Now, it does not make sense to repeat the same cities in many rows. This could lead you to typos, excessive space usage, difficulties to bring up results among other problems. So you use a foreign key:

```
id   | name    | fk_city
-------------------------
1      Alice     1
2      Bob       2
45     Eve       2
988    Bill      1
```

home city table:

```
id   | name
-------------------------
1    | San Francisco
2    | New York
```

Hope it makes things clearer for you. :-)

**Update**: about your final question: Yes. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A foreign key is a column in one table that should uniquely identify something in another table. Thus, the values should correspond to primary keys in that other table.

For example, if you have a table of students taking courses, every record would include a student id and a course id. These are foreign keys into a student table (where there is one record for each student id), and a courses table (where there is one record for each course id).

Referential integrity means that all your foreign keys actually correspond to primary keys in these target tables. For example, all the student ids and course ids in your registration table correspond to real student ids and course ids.

Answer (score 1):

```
id   | name    | whatever | countryid
-------------------------------------
1      Alice     ....       13
2      Bob       ....       42
45     Eve       ....       1
988    ....      ....       2

id   | countryid
----------------
1      Japan
2      Spain
13     Norway
42     Italy
```

The foreign key points from the person table (first) to a row in the country table (second)

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key is the primary key from another table stored on your table. Say you have a table of customers and a table of orders. The CustomerId is likely the primary key on the customer table, and the OrderId is likely the primary key on the order table. But on the order table you need to know the customer for this order, no? Therefore you need to store the CustomerId on the order table. In this case the CustomerId on the order table is a foreign key.

I would point out that there is no requirement that a primary key (and therefore a foreign key) be a single column. It's simpler, sure. But I've worked on enterprise systems where the primary key was 11 columns long, and I'm sure there are examples longer than that. That is, you needed to know the value for 11 different columns before you can uniquely identify the row.

Comment: Best definition that I have come across.

Answer (score 0):

In a relational database a one-to-many relationship is implemented by having the child table reference the ID of the parent table. The parent ID in the Child table is called a Foreign Key as it references a primary key of another table.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key is a field that references another table in the database. For example, suppose you had 2 tables, `PERSON` and `ADDRESS`. There is a field in `PERSON` called `ID` and a field in `ADDRESS` called `PERSON_ID`. You would make `PERSON_ID` refer to `PERSON.ID` as a foreign key. What this means is that you can't have an address that is not connected to a person, since the value in the `ADDRESS.PERSON_ID` field must exist in the table `PERSON`.

Answer (score 0):

using your table example, assume you have another table:

```
cartid  |  id  | itemid
-----------------------
100        1       abc
101        1       cde
```

in this table, the primary key is the cartid, the foreign key is the id, which would be linked to your first table. user 1 has two carts, each cart having one item each.

a foreign key is the what you use to link two or more tables that have related information to each other.