# In Django 1.8, what does "USERNAME_FIELD" mean by authentication system?

Tags: python, django

I have been learning Django for a week, In order to implement authentication system, I have created models.py file as tutorials.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    username = models.CharField('username', max_length = 10, unique = True, db_index = True)
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique = True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    is_active = models.BoolenField(default = True)
    is_admin = models.BoolenField(default = False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.username
```

I understand what **username, email, joined, is_active, is_admin** means, but I can't understand why I use **USERNAME_FIELD**.

Is **username** created by *models.CharField* equal to the **'username'** in *USERNAME_FIELD*?

Why do I have to create **USERNAME_FIELD**?

What does **def __unicode__(self):** function mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/), USERNAME_FIELD is:

> A string describing the name of the field on the user model that is used as the unique identifier. This will usually be a username of some kind, but it can also be an email address, or any other unique identifier. The field must be unique (i.e., have unique=True set in its definition), unless you use a custom authentication backend that can support non-unique usernames.

So, `USERNAME_FIELD` specifies which model field is going to be used as the username. If your application uses an email address instead of a username, you would configure that using `USERNAME_FIELD`.

The `__unicode__(self)` method returns a string representation of the object. Without it, any time you try to display an object it will look like: `<User: User object>`. As you have it now, displaying a User object will instead show the User's username. In the Django tutorial [part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api) they use the `__str__` method in conjunction with the `@python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator to make it work with Python 2. In Python 3 `__str__` is the equivalent of `__unicode__` in Python 2.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Would you tell me ForeignKey? I can't understand what the ForeignKey exactly means.

Comment: A foreign key is a reference to a row in a table. It is a way to link two rows. Here is a question that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655446/what-exactly-is-a-foreign-key

Answer (score 1):

Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD) for your version of Django:

> **USERNAME_FIELD**
>
> A string describing the name of the field on the User model that is used as the unique identifier. This will usually be a username of
>   some kind, but it can also be an email address, or any other unique
>   identifier. The field *must* be unique (i.e., have **unique=True** set in
>   its definition).

`USERNAME_FIELD` defaults to `"username"` so you can skip setting it in your custom user model if the default works for you.

You can read about `__str__()` and  `__unicode__()` methods [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you explain more exactly? I appreciate your hospitality.