# Relational room database: The class must be either entity or database view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to understand how to use Room with relational tables. I have created a Job model, that has a list of locations and therefore needs a 1-to-many relation between the Job and Location object. For that, I have created a JobWrapper data class to hold both the Job and the locations. But, when building I get the following error:

> The class must be either @Entity or @DatabaseView. -
> java.util.Collectionerror: Entities and POJOs must have a usable
> public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor
> whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). -
> java.util.Collection \models\JobWrapper.java:12: error: Cannot find
> the child entity column `parentId` in java.util.Collection.
> Options:
> private java.util.Collection<models.Location> locations;
> public final class JobWrapper {
> ^   Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
> JobWrapper(models.Job,java.util.Collection<models.Location>)
> -> [param:job -> matched field:job, param:locations -> matched field:unmatched] models\JobWrapper.java:9:
> error: Cannot find setter for field.

I notice that it at least cannot find the locations table. But, I do not know how to handle the problem. The problem did not appear while reading from the database - it first appeared when I was trying to put data into the database with my JobDAO. I have already spent a day trying to solve it and are therefore searching for a solution or some advise on how to solve it.

*Note: I have been following the following guides:*

1. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many
2. https://dev.to/normanaspx/android-room-how-works-one-to-many-relationship-example-5ad0

Here follows some relevant code snippets from my projects:

**JobWrapper.kt**

```
data class JobWrapper(
    @Embedded val job: Job,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "jobid",
        entityColumn = "parentId"
    ) var locations : Collection<Location>
)
```

**Job**

```
@Entity
data class Job (
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    var jobid : String,

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "job_status")
    var status : JobStatus,

    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("createdByAuth0Id")
    var creator : String,

    @SerializedName("note")
    var note : String?,

    @NonNull
    var organisationId : String,

    @NonNull
    var type : JobType,

    @SerializedName("atCustomerId")
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "working_at_customer_id")
    var workingAtCustomerId : String,

    @SerializedName("toCustomerId")
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "working_to_customer_id")
    var workingToCustomerId : String,
)
```

**JobStatus.kt**

```
enum class JobStatus {
    CREATED,
    READY,
    IN_PROGRESS,
    FINISHED
}
```

**Location.kt**

```
@Entity
data class Location (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var entityId: Long,

    @NonNull
    var parentId: String,

    @NonNull
    var locationId: String,

    @NonNull
    var type: String
) {
    constructor() : this(0, "", "", "")
}
```

**JobDao.kt**

```
@Dao
interface JobDAO {
    @Transaction
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(job: JobWrapper)

    @Transaction
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(jobs: List<JobWrapper>)

    @Transaction
    @Update
    fun update(job: JobWrapper)

    @Transaction
    @Delete
    fun delete(job: JobWrapper)

    @Transaction
    @Query("DELETE FROM Job")
    fun deleteAll()

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Job")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<JobWrapper>>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **Kraigolas** has pointed out you can only use JobWrapper directly to extract data you need to insert/delete/update via the actual underlying Entities.

Consider the following

- (unlike Kraigolas's solultion the extended functions are in the JobDao rather than in a repository(swings and roundabouts argument as to which is better))
- note to test I've made some changes for brevity and convenience so the you would have to amend to suit.

**JobDao**

```
@Dao
interface JobDAO {

    /* Core/Underlying DAO's */
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(job: Job): Long
    @Insert()
    fun insert(location: List<Location>): List<Long>
    @Transaction
    @Delete
    fun delete(location: List<Location>)
    @Delete
    fun delete(job: Job)
    @Update
    fun update(job: Job)
    @Update
    fun update(location: List<Location>)

    @Transaction
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(job: JobWrapper): Long {
        val rv =insert(job.job)
        insert(job.locations)
        return rv
    }

    @Transaction
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(jobs: List<JobWrapper>) {
        for (jw: JobWrapper in jobs) {
            insert(jw)
        }
    }

    @Transaction
    @Update
    fun update(job: JobWrapper) {
        update(job.locations)
        update(job.job)
    }

    /* Delete according to JobWrapper allowing optional deletion of locations */
    @Transaction
    @Delete
    fun delete(job: JobWrapper, deleteChildLocations: Boolean) {
        if (deleteChildLocations) {
            delete(job.locations)
        }
        delete(job.job)
    }

    /* will orphan locations as is */
    /* Note using Foreign Keys in Location (to Job) with ON DELETE CASCADE */
    @Transaction
    @Query("DELETE FROM Job")
    fun deleteAll()

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Job")
    fun getAll(): List<JobWrapper>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM job WHERE jobid = :jobid")
    fun getJobWrapperByJobId(jobid: String ): JobWrapper
}
```

- As can be seen the Core Dao's include Job and Location actions
- The JobWrapper actions invoke the Core actions
- List have been used instead of Collections for my convenience (aka I only dabble with Kotlin)
- Instead of JobType, type has been changed to use String for convenience

As I've tested this the demo/example used follows (obviously JobDao is as above)

The POJO's and Entities used are/were :-

**JobWrapper**

```
 data class JobWrapper(
    @Embedded val job: Job,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "jobid",
        entityColumn = "parentId",
        entity = Location::class
    ) var locations : List<Location>
)
```

- **List** instead of Collection

**Job**

```
@Entity
data class Job (
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    var jobid : String,

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "job_status")
    var status : String,

    @NonNull
    var creator : String,

    var note : String?,

    @NonNull
    var organisationId : String,

    @NonNull
    var type : String,

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "working_at_customer_id")
    var workingAtCustomerId : String,

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "working_to_customer_id")
    var workingToCustomerId : String,
)
```

- largely the same but String rather than objects for convenience

**Location**

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Job::class,
            parentColumns = ["jobid"],
            childColumns = ["parentId"],
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ])
data class Location (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var entityId: Long,

    @NonNull
    var parentId: String,

    @NonNull
    var locationId: String,

    @NonNull
    var type: String
) {
    constructor() : this(0, "", "", "")
}
```

- Foreign Key added for referential integrity and also CASCADE deletes (UPDATE CASCADE not really required unless you change a jobid, other updates aren't cascaded (and wouldn't need to be))

@Database used **JobDatabase**

```
@Database(entities = [Location::class,Job::class],version = 1)
abstract class JobDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getJobDao(): JobDAO
    
    companion object {
        var instance: JobDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): JobDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, JobDatabase::class.java, "job.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as JobDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- allowMainThreadQueries used to allow testing on main thread

The test/demo activity **MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: JobDatabase
    lateinit var dao: JobDAO
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = JobDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getJobDao()

        var jobId: String = "Job1"
        var jw = JobWrapper(
            Job(
                jobId,
                "x",
                "Fred",
                "Note for Job1",
                "Org1",
                "A","Cust1",
                "Cust1"),
            listOf(
                Location(0,jobId,"loc1","J"),
                Location(0,jobId,"Loc2","K"),
                Location(0,jobId,"Loc3","L")
            )
        )
        dao.insert(jw)
        dao.insertAll(createJobWrapperList(10))
        dao.delete(dao.getJobWrapperByJobId("job6"),true)
        var jobWrapper = dao.getJobWrapperByJobId("job7")
        jobWrapper.job.creator = "update creator"
        for (l in jobWrapper.locations) {
            if (l.type == "M") l.type= "UPDATED"
        }
        dao.update(jobWrapper)
    }

    fun createJobWrapperList(numberToCreate: Int): List<JobWrapper> {
        val l = mutableListOf<JobWrapper>()
        for(i in 1..numberToCreate) {
            var jid = "job$i"
            l.add(
                JobWrapper(
                Job(jid,"X","Creator$i","Note for $jid","org$jid","T","custA","custT"),
                    arrayListOf(
                        Location(0,jid,"loc_$jid.1","L"),
                        Location(0,jid,"loc_$jid.2","M"),
                        Location(0,jid,"loc_$jid.3","N")
                    )
                )
            )
        }
        return l.toList()
    }
}
```

This :-

1. gets DB instance and the dao.
2. adds a job and it's location via a single JobWrapper
3. adds x (10) jobs and 3 locations per Job via a List of JobWrappers generated via the `createJobWrapperList` function.
   4.deletes the a JobWrapper obtained via `getJobWrapperByJobId` including deleting the underlying locations (`true`) using `delete` for the JobWrapper associated with the jobid "job6".
4. obtains the JobWrapper associated with "job7" changes the creator and changes the locations that have a type of "M" to "UPDATED" *(just the one)* and then uses the `update(JobWrapper)` to apply the updates.

**WARNING**

Inserting using a JobWrapper, as it has REPLACE conflict strategy will result in additional locations if it replaces as the entityId will always be generated.

**Result**

Runinng the above results in :-

**Job** Table :-

[image]

- As can be seen job6 has been deleted (11 rows added 10 left) and job7's creator has been updated.

**Location** Table :-

[image]

- As can be seen no job6 locations (was 33 locations (11 * 3) now 30) and the location that was type M has been updated according to the JobWrapper passed.

You asked :-

> How do I ensure the relationship to the right parent (job) when inserting the childs (locations)?

I think the above demonstrates how.

Comment: Very nice answer and very great with all the extra effort you made :)
I will try it out right away :D

Comment: This is very nice. But, I am still not fully understanding how the location gets its reference for the parent job. 

I am getting this error: NOT NULL constraint failed: Location.parent_id (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)

My best guess is that something is missing in the JobDao.kt

Comment: Oh I see, you are adding it to the objects manually in the create funtions.

Comment: @7heViking yep to build a JobWrapper for insertion, you must know the jobid up front. so you simply use that.

Comment: I'm on Room version 2.5.0

Comment: I have a similar case except mine uses a junction table:     data class JobPW(
    @Embedded val job: Job,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "job_id",
        entityColumn = "worker_id",
        associateBy = Junction(JobWorkerCrossRef::class)
    )
    val workers: List<Worker>,

    @Relation(
        entity = Poster::class,
        parentColumn = "job_id",
        entityColumn = "job_id_map"
    )
    val posters: List<PosterWithWorker>) : Serializable  When I try to retrieve the object with there are no workers.  Do I have to manually enter into the junction table?

Comment: @user1743524 yes you have to add rows into the junction table. No rows in the junction table = no related data. It is impossible for the database to know what should be related to what.

Answer (score 2):

`JobWrapper` does not have an associated table with it. Note that it is nice for pulling from your database because it will grab from the `Location` table *and* the `Job` table, but it makes no sense to insert into your database with a `JobWrapper` because there is no associated table for it.

Instead, you need to insert `Job`s, and `Location`s separately. The database can query for them together because they are related by `jobid` and `parentid`, so you don't have to worry about them losing their relationship to each other, and you can still query for your `JobWrapper`.

If given my above explanation you still think that you should be able to insert a `JobWrapper`, then you might create a repository with a method like:

```
suspend fun insertWrapper(wrapper : JobWrapper){
    dao.insertJob(wrapper.job)
    dao.insertLocations(wrapper.locations)
}
```

Where `insertJob` inserts a single `Job`, and `insertLocations` inserts a list of `Location`.

Comment: Alright, that sounds as a solution. Just one question. How do I ensure the relationship to the right parent (job) when inserting the childs (locations)?

Comment: @7heViking In a relational database (that is what SQL, which room overlays, is) relationships are handled by [foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/655460/11659881). One way you might do this is by adding a `jobid` to every location, as from what I can see, you have a **one-to-many relationship**: one `Job` can have many `Location`. Then, room will grab every `Location` where the `jobid` from `Location` matches the `jobid` from `Job`. I suggest downloading SQLite Studio or something of the sort, and practicing *without* room first so that you can get a good understanding.

Comment: I have a smiliar situation except I am using junction tables to handle the many-to-many relationships, and also one for 0-1 relationship.  I thought that it would be impossible to enter the data directly without entering the relation row in the junction table.   Is Room smart enough to recognize that there is a junction table there and use it?  I'm also not sure how to handle the id generation.  When I create a job I need to first get the job id before I can enter the rest of the information for the cross reference tables