# Cannot insert row in Oracle DB table with FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert row to table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name1 (
        id_name1 NUMBER,
        id_name2 NUMBER,
        id_name3 NUMBER,
        datevalue TIMESTAMP,
        value_name1 NUMBER,
        PRIMARY KEY (id_name1),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_name2) REFERENCES table_name2 (id_name2),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_name3) REFERENCES table_name3 (id_name3)
```

table_name2 is empty
table_name3 have some data

Insert query:

```
INSERT INTO table_name1 (
    id_name1, 
    id_name2, 
    id_name3, 
    datevalue,  
    value_name1
)
VALUES (
    1, 
    1,  
    1, 
    TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-03 13:29:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
    1
)
```

While executing query i have this error:

SQL Error [2291] [23000]: ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated (SYSTEM.SYS_C008315) - source key not found

Error position: line: 1

I think the problem in inserting values to table with foreign keys. Who can say what the problem is?

Comment: foreitn key means that the number 1 in id_name2 has to exist prior to the insert in table_name2  the concept is easy the same goes of course for all other foreign key as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is a foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655446/what-exactly-is-a-foreign-key)

Comment: Oh, boy. The 1st BIG mistake you've made is to use **SYSTEM** schema for your playground. If you want to destroy the database, continue doing so. If not, create another user and brush your SQL skills there. SYS, as well as SYSTEM, are *special*, they own the database and should be used for maintenance purposes only. They are VERY powerful so, if you don't pay attention to what you're doing (reading your question, I'd say that you aren't that experienced Oracle user), you might really harm the database.

Comment: thanks guys for you answers. And sorry for simple question, i worked only with select query and FK. I will use "create user" command to avoid using SYSTEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has largely been given in the comments, but trying to write it down.

In order to have a foreign key, the table you are referring to has to exist (which makes your example somewhat incomplete as the other two tables are not created) and in addition any key that you want to refer to has to exist *before* you can insert things into your `table_name1`.

To write this down as a somewhat complete example you could stick into an sqlfiddle also:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name2 (
        id_name2    NUMBER,
        value_name2 NUMBER,
        PRIMARY KEY(id_name2)
);

CREATE TABLE table_name3 (
        id_name3    NUMBER,
        value_name3 NUMBER,
        PRIMARY KEY(id_name3)
);

CREATE TABLE table_name1 (
        id_name1 NUMBER,
        id_name2 NUMBER,
        id_name3 NUMBER,
        datevalue TIMESTAMP,
        value_name1 NUMBER,
        PRIMARY KEY (id_name1),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_name2) REFERENCES table_name2 (id_name2),
        FOREIGN KEY (id_name3) REFERENCES table_name3 (id_name3)    
);
```

Note that the order matters in that `table_name2` and `table_name3` have to be created before `table_name1` as otherwise the `REFERENCES` obviously has nothing to refer to.

To insert/select

```
INSERT INTO table_name2 (
    id_name2, 
    value_name2
)
VALUES (
    2, -- id_name2
    42
  );


INSERT INTO table_name3 (
    id_name3, 
    value_name3
)
VALUES (
    3, -- id_name2
    999
 );

INSERT INTO table_name1 (
    id_name1, 
    id_name2, 
    id_name3, 
    datevalue,  
    value_name1
)
VALUES (
    1, -- id_name1
    2, -- id_name2
    3, -- id_name3
    TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-03 13:29:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
    1
);

select * from table_name1;
select * from table_name2;
select * from table_name3;
```

also here order matters as you first have to have the keys in `table_name2` and `table_name3` before you can insert (and thus refer to them) in `table_name1`

Comment: Thank you Eric, for you answer. I will rebuild logic of query and more dig in to fk and insert theme.

Comment: @Motixa, you are welcome. If the answer has been useful, you can consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark next to it. The other comments on your question are obviously also highly relevant, so also take a look at those.